# Are Windows CE controls designed without Automation support?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, ui-automation

I am working on the automation of WinCE applications and found following details so far.

- WPF controls support UI automation through AutomationPeer class.
- WinForm controls support UI automation through ControlAccessibleObject class

But the WinCE controls does not implement/inherit any of the classes through which we can get controls for UI automation.

Q. 1 - Does it mean that WinCE controls are not designed for UI automation?

Q.2 - What are the ways to automate winCE application?

Q.3 - Is there any Microsoft best practices to implement on the WinCE controls in order to automate them?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

WinCE controls are mostly wrappers over the corresponding Windows API controls, which means that you may automate them "old-style", i.e. by sending/posting them windows messages.